# MDM Managed M2 14 inch MBP rebooting into recovery after Sonoma 14.3.1 update

Tags: recovery, filevault, mdm

I am locked out of my Apple Silicon Macbook. I was on macOS Sonoma 14.3. Around when 14.3.1 update was released, the device prompted restart after update.

After restart mac is rebooting into recovery mode and asking for recovery key to proceed. No other option typically in recoveryOS, Restore TimeMachine Backup, Re Install macOS options are shown. When I try to use existing recovery key, it says `Supplied password failed to decrypt the disk`.

I am not able to unlock the startup disk using local admin user accounts either. After choosing the account and respective password, the dialog box just shakes and stays the same without showing any specific error message. Is there anyway I could get access to data in the disk? Since it is an MDM managed disk, chances are it might be rotating recovery keys as well I guess.

Comment: Please contact the entity which is controlling the MDM for help.